# Redirecting https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com in iis

Tags: iis, redirect

I redirect from http://domain.com to https://www.domain.com with this:

```
<rule name="Add WWW prefix" >
   <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

And I redirect from http://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com with this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

But how do I redirect from https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com ?